# What exactly is a byte and what does it have to do with binary?

Tags: c#, binary, byte, bit

I'm just learning about binary and bytes. I understand that 8 bits make up a byte and that a byte can have 256 possibilities. The thing I am confused about is this:

```
byte[] b = new byte[] { 85, 85, 67, 75 };
```

What does 85 or any of the numbers above have to do with binary. There is simply something not fully clicking in my mind.

Comment: "There is no question too simple". "There is no question too simple". "There is no question too simple". It's not working.

Comment: `85` has nothing to do with `binary`, because it is `decimal`. `85 base 10` == `1010101 base 2`. It's just a way of representing a number

Comment: Isn't that code block just declaring an array of bytes and each number represents a different byte?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Binary is how things are stored inside the computer. Ones and zeros, on and off, true and false, the presence or absence of an electric current. [This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system) gives it a fairly thorough treatment.

A representation like "85" in your example is how a byte is **formatted** for our convenience as human readers. It could be formatted in hexadecimal (base 16) as "55", in octal (base 8) as "125" in binary as "1010101", or even "11" in base-84 if you were so inclined. All mean the same thing.

Comment: Sorry to contradict you, but a zero is not the absence of electric current, it's just a different amount of it. Not that the OP probably cares about that.

Comment: @Chris: Of course... high and low logic states. I over simplified.

Comment: @Chris It depends on the way it's implemented, actually. And it's usually potential, not current.

Comment: To further nitpick, logic levels, in common hardware logic circuit implementations, are represented by two different voltage levels, rather than current levels.  (Though in some RAM implementations, one could argue that the bit state is really a stored electrical charge.)

Answer (score 5):

85 is simply a decimal (i.e. "base 10") [positional notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) of a number. It means:

> 8***10**^1 + 5***10**^0
>
> = 8*10 + 5*1
>
> = 80 + 5
>
> = 85

However, you can choose any base to represent numbers. Us humans have 10 fingers which is the probable origin of the "base 10" system in everyday use, but there is no way to represent 10 different digits in the physical circuitry of the computer. This circuitry only understands lack of electrons versus presence of electrons - i.e. only two digits, hence binary system.

So, while you can write decimal 85 in your program's source code (to keep it more natural to humans), it ultimately gets represented within the computer as binary 1010101, which equals...

> 1***2**^6 + 0***2**^5 + 1***2**^4 + 0***2**^3 + 1***2**^2 + 0***2**^1 + 1***2**^0
>
> = 1*64 + 0*32 + 1*16 + 0*8 + 1*4 + 0*2 + 1*1
>
> = 64 + 16 + 4 + 1
>
> = 85

---

BTW, decimal system does not "align" with binary - a single decimal digit cannot be represented by a "whole" number of binary digits and round decimal numbers do not match well the round binary numbers. For example:

- 10 (decimal) = 1010 (binary)
- 100 (decimal) = 1100100 (binary)
- 1000 (decimal) = 1111101000 (binary)
- etc...

Sometimes, it is convenient to use a numeric system that does "align" with binary, such as [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) (one octal digit is exactly 3 binary digits) or [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) (one hexadecimal digit is exactly 4 binary digits).

The important point is that all these systems eventually get represented as binary within the computer.

*On a side-note: "hexa-decimal" used to be "**sexa**-decimal", but apparently offended some puritanic sensitivities ;)*

Answer (score 3):

A [byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in C# is just an 8-bit integer value. In the above, you're representing 4 numbers in an array - this is really no different than it would be if you used int, except that the numbers take 1/4th of the total space in  memory.

It actually has nothing to do with "binary" - other than it's the most common representation used for binary data.  This is because most systems thing about one "byte" at a time, which is an 8 bit block of data.  As such, a byte is a common way to represent this data if you're doing something that works with raw binary information.

The [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class has routines for going from byte arrays to other types and back.  For example, it can [take 4 bytes and turn it into an Int32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32.aspx) value or go the other way around.  Remember - all data stored is just memory - you're just saving a sequence of bits (1's and 0's) in a specific order, and the system is interpreting this data in a specific way.

Answer (score 3):

Those are just numbers. They have nothing to do with binary per se. You can write them out in binary, though, if you so chose - eg, 75 = 01001011 in base 2.

A `byte` here, then, is just a data type which can hold one of 256 possible values. Typically this is interpreted either as a number from 0 to 255, or 8 binary digits (ie, 8 ON/OFF values). These are just two ways of looking at the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

That statement declares an array of bytes, and assigns to it 4 elements - each of those being a single byte (in theory!) in size. The actual values - 85, 86, 67, 75 - stored in that array are each values that can fit into a single byte. In your code sample, those values are represented in decimal form. Once your code is translated into executable form, those values will eventually be seen by your computer in their binary representations, bandied about from register to register, pushed, popped, and accumulated, etc.

You *could* represent values in other bases within your source - hexadecimal, or base 16, for instance, which is closer to the metal than decimal, and correspondingly allows your thought process to move easily between human representation and what your code is actually saying since there's virtually no actual math to mentally go between hex and binary; another good example is octal.

Or you can think of it this way: represent values within your code using the base that best relates to what you're doing. If you're OR'ing together permissions or color values, hex or octal; if you're calculating interest on a checking account, then the obvious choice is decimal.

Now, for your specific code snippet - if you're dealing with individual characters or writing raw stuff to a block device, an array of bytes might be just fine - however, as you become one with your compiler, your brain may eventually consider hex the easier-to-handle representation.

Comment: ...and I always see things after the fact that I would like to have mentioned before others, but I lose again: squeezing for storage efficiency is another reason you might use type byte instead of type int.

Comment: How did you get such a good grasp of this? Online or in school?

Comment: Certainly not school - I darn near flunked out of high school, and went no further. Not online either; books, experimentation, hard knocks, and many nights just me, my compiler, and copious quantities of piping-hot coffee.

Find yourself a practical - and pressing! - need to program something, anything. If the need is absolutely dire, and the deadline is first thing in the morning, you can get pretty good real quick. :)

Answer (score 0):

Each of the numbers in the array are less than 256. They are converted to a byte in binary. This is just their decimal representation.